# Excel VBA .export to workbook location

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for help here, I am stuck with my code.
It should export certain cells of my excle sheet as JPG image and save it.
I want it to be saved at the same location as the excle workbook is, but I a not able to make it work.It works fine if I give the location manually
The code itself was alredy copied from other threads and I understood it has to be like this in order to awoit a "wait" command.
This is my code, the error code is marked in bolt:

Public Sub Grafik_picture()

```
Dim objChartObject As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Grafik_sheet").Select

ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E18").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Set objChartObject = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, Range("A1:B10").Width, Range("A1:B10").Height)

With objChartObject

   .Select

    .Parent.Activate

    With .Chart

        .Paste

        **.Export ActiveWorkbook.Path & "grafic-export.jpg", "JPG"**

    End With

    .Delete

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

By default the `.Export` method will save the output in the same location as the Excel file.

I don't know what error you are getting, but try replacing

`.Export ActiveWorkbook.Path & "grafic-export.jpg", "JPG"`

with

`.Export "grafic-export.jpg", "JPG"`

It's possible that you are creating an invalid path by trying to concatenate `ActiveWorkbook.Path` with the desired filename and type.